# How to pass State in Context React and use this an another components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying this code with useContext. i want to take this response.data.message in Editdata.js component. how did i do? how i will send this state message using context.

auth-context.js

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  updatePlayer: () => {},
});

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {

  const [msg, setmsg] = useState();

  const playerupdate = async (updatedPlayer) => {
    const { id, player_fname, player_lname, player_nickname } = updatedPlayer;

    await axios
      .post(
        "https://scorepad.ominfowave.com/api/adminPlayerUpdate",
        JSON.stringify({ id, player_fname, player_lname, player_nickname }),
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        fetchPlayerList()
        //navigate('/view-players');
        setmsg(response.data.message)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        updatePlayer: playerupdate
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

type here
```

Editdata.js

```
function Editdata() {
  const authcon = useContext(AuthContext);

    const submitupdateForm = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();    
      const playerdetail = {
        player_fname: firstname,
        player_lname: lastname,
        player_nickname: nickname,
        id: empid
      }
      authcon.updatePlayer(playerdetail)

    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={submitupdateForm}>
      </form>
    );
}
```

How is the correct way to pass state between components with useContext?

Comment: Is Editdata a child of AuthContextProvider?

Comment: Yes,  i set AuthContextProvider inside index.js. Editdata is child of App component.

(  <AuthContextProvider>
    <App />
  </AuthContextProvider>)

Comment: You should create a more simple non-async sample component to test your use of context. Once you figure out how to use it properly, move onto more complex use cases.